# Let $ f(x) ∈ F[x] \ $ and $ \ a ∈ F \ $. Show that $ \ f(x) \ $ and $ \ f(x + a) \ $ have the same splitting field over $ \ F $

Tags: extension-field, splitting-field

Let $  f(x) ∈ F[x]  \ $ and $ \ a ∈ F \ $. Show that $ \ f(x) \ $ and  $ \ f(x + a) \ $ have the same splitting field over $  \ F  $

**Answer:**

Let $ \ E \ $ be the splitting field of $ \ f \ $ over $ \ F \ $.

Since $ \ E \ $ is the splitting field of $ \ f \ $ over $ \ F \ $ , $ \ E \ $ is generated over $ \ F \ $ by the roots of $ \ f \ $.

Thus $ f(x) \ $ and $ \ f(x+a ) \ $ have same splitting field $ \ E \ $ as $ \ a \in F \ $

**Am I right so far ?**

**Help me out**

Comment: I would add a question, what are the roots of the polynomial $f(x+a)$? Also, what do you exactly have in mind when writing "Thus" at the third line of your answer?

Comment: I thing both $ f(x) \ $ and $ \ f(x+a) \ $ have same roots over $ \ F \ $.  Is not it ?

Comment: Maybe a concrete example will help you out. Let $f(x)=x(x+1)$ and $a$ be $-3$. Then $f(x+a)=(x-3)(x-2)$. What are the roots of $f(x)$ and the roots of  $f(x+a)$?

Comment: So the roots of $x^2+1=0$ and $(x+1)^2+1=0$ are the same?? @yourmath

Comment: so how to proceed ?

Comment: Ok, I have given an example where the roots of $f(x)$ are $0$ and $1$ and the roots of $f(x-3)$ are $-3$ and $-2$ right? I claim that there is a general and simple rule that you can extract from this example relating the roots of $f(x)$ and $f(x-a)$ in general. This rule will help you backing up the "Thus" in the third line of your answer. If you want me to check your full answer, just post it as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 4):

If $x$ is a root of $f$, $f(x)=0$, this is equivalent to saying that $f(x-a+a)=0$, i.e $x-a$ is a root of $f(x+a)$, so if $x_1,..,x_n$ are the roots of $f$, $x_1-a,..,x_n-a$ are the roots of $f(x+a)$.

The field generated by $x_1,...,x_n$ contains $x_i-a$ since $a\in F$. The field generated by $x_1-a,..., x_n-a$ contains $x_i=x_i-a+a$ since $a\in F$.